# In React, 'prevState' is used to transfer data from the previous state to the new state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I'm working on a small pet project website to watch anime using React, react-router-dom, and redux-toolkit with rtk-query. I encountered a problem: I want the information about the episodes that the user has watched and the last episode they watched to be stored in localStorage. I need this so that the user knows which episodes they have already watched, and when they revisit the anime, the last episode they watched is displayed. It seems to be working fine, but when I switch to a new anime, the data about the previously watched episodes from the previous anime somehow gets mixed in. Here's an example:

Let's say I opened the anime "Jujutsu Kaisen 2nd Season" and watched 4 episodes. My localStorage looks like this:
`Jujutsu Kaisen 2nd Season_WATCHED_EPISODE: ["jujutsu-kaisen-2nd-season-episode-10", "jujutsu-kaisen-2nd-season-episode-8", "jujutsu-kaisen-2nd-season-episode-5", "jujutsu-kaisen-2nd-season-episode-1"]`

Then, I use the search function to switch to another anime, let's say "Dr. Stone" and choose any episode. Now my localStorage gets merged with the previous state:
`Dr. Stone: New World Part 2 (Dub)_WATCHED_EPISODE: ["jujutsu-kaisen-2nd-season-episode-10", "jujutsu-kaisen-2nd-season-episode-8", "jujutsu-kaisen-2nd-season-episode-5", "jujutsu-kaisen-2nd-season-episode-1", "dr-stone-new-world-part-2-dub-episode-1"]`

What I want is for it to be like this:
`Dr. Stone: New World Part 2 (Dub)_WATCHED_EPISODE: ["dr-stone-new-world-part-2-dub-episode-1"]`

I see this as the previous state somehow leaking into the new one.

I want to mention that I have been familiar with React and all the technologies you mentioned for less than a month, so I would really appreciate it if you could suggest improvements or alternative approaches. I sometimes feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here.

Here is the link to the [project](https://github.com/Mirsmog/RTK-AniList)

To run the project locally, make a copy of it, navigate to its directory, and then `yarn dev` or `npm run dev`.

I apologize for any mistakes in my English. If something is unclear, please let me know, and I'll do my best to explain.

```
    import React from "react";
    import { useGetAnimeEpisodeQuery } from "../../services/animeApi";
    import { AnimeInfo } from "../../services/types/AnimeInfo";
    interface PlayerProps extends AnimeInfo {}
    const Player: React.FC<PlayerProps> = ({ image, episodes, title }) => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem(title + "_LAST_EPISODE")) {
        localStorage.setItem(title + "_LAST_EPISODE", JSON.stringify(episodes[0].id));
    }
      const localLastEpisode = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(title + "_LAST_EPISODE") ||                       episodes[0].id);
    const localWatched = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(title + "_WATCHED_EPISODE") || `["${episodes[0].id}"]`);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentEpisode(localLastEpisode);
    }, [localLastEpisode]);

    const [completed, setCompleted] = React.useState(false);
    const [watched, setWatched] = React.useState<string[]>(localWatched);
    const [currentEpisode, setCurrentEpisode] = React.useState(localLastEpisode);
    const { data: seria, isLoading, isSuccess, error } = useGetAnimeEpisodeQuery(currentEpisode);
    const episodeUrl = seria ? seria.headers.Referer : "";

    const setEpisode = (episodeId: string) => {
        setCurrentEpisode(episodeId);
        localStorage.setItem(title + "_LAST_EPISODE", JSON.stringify(episodeId));
        if (!watched.includes(episodeId)) {
            setWatched((prev) => [episodeId, ...prev]);
        }
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (watched.length > 0) {
            localStorage.setItem(title + "_WATCHED_EPISODE", JSON.stringify(watched));
        }
    }, [watched]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const checkHendler = () => {
            setTimeout(() => setCompleted(true), 5000);
        };
        isSuccess || isLoading ? checkHendler() : setCompleted(false);
    }, [isSuccess, isLoading]);

    if (error) return <div>Get some bad request</div>;

    return (
        <div className="mb-20">
            <div className="w-full h-[576px] full-bl relative bg-black overflow-hidden mx-auto">
                <div
                    style={{ "--anime-bg-url": `url(${image})` } as React.CSSProperties}
                    className={`relative w-full h-full bg-black z-10 after:bg-[image:--anime-bg-url] scale-110 after:bg-no-repeat after:bg-cover top-0 right-0 after:bg-center blur-xl brightness-50 ${
                        completed && "hidden"
                    } after:absolute after:inset-8 after:top-0 after:right-0 after:w-full after:h-full after:content-[''] after:bg-black after:z-[20]`}
                ></div>
                <iframe
                    allow="autoplay"
                    allowFullScreen
                    scrolling="no"
                    src={episodeUrl}
                    className={`w-full h-full bg-black bg-[image:--anime-bg-url] bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center ${
                        !completed && "blur-xl brightness-50"
                    } flex items-center justify-center`}
                ></iframe>
                {!completed && <span className="loading loading-dots text-info absolute w-24 spinnerPos z-10"></span>}
            </div>
            <ul className="flex gap-3 flex-wrap px-2 py-2 max-h-48 overflow-y-auto bg-slate-900">
                {episodes.map((episode) => (
                    <li
                        onClick={() => setEpisode(episode.id)}
                        className={`${
                            watched.includes(episode.id) &&
                            episode.id !== currentEpisode &&
                            "opacity-50 bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700"
                        } ${
                            episode.id === currentEpisode && "bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700"
                        } text-white btn-square btn text-lg w-12 border-none`}
                        key={episode.id}
                    >
                        {episode.number}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Player;
```

tried to do everything I could

Comment: I suggest you have a cleaner data structure instead of adding `_WATCHED_EPISODE` suffix (like maybe just use a simple array of object which contains id and episodesId properties). and to manage data on localStorage, you can use `useLocalStorage` hook from mantine library which is like `useState` but it saves the data on the `localStorage`

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, I will definitely use this, I think the current localStorage job seems cumbersome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the component has not unmounted, then the `watched` state variable will still retain the values from the previous render.

In the following section:

```js
if (!watched.includes(episodeId)) {
    setWatched((prev) => [episodeId, ...prev]);
}
```

I suspect your 'Player.tsx' is not unmounting when changing the video that is being played.

If you don't want to unmount the component, I would suggest something like the following to reset the watched state when the title changes:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setWatched(localWatched)
}, [title]); // Only re-run the effect if title changes
```

You can read more about useState here: https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked out, I honestly didn't think the solution was that simple.